# Creating a sleek re-sizable website that preserves its layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a sleek re-sizable website. After doing a bit of reading I found that the way to achieve this is having a parent node with a rigidly defined size, and children with % sizes. On the w3schools website it says that in 2012 85% of monitors has a resolution greater than 1024.

My question is, in order to implement a re-sizeable website the preserves its layout, what is the best size for the fixed-size parent node in order for it to be compatible and consistent on all monitors?

Comment: I would definitely give [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) a look if you're looking for "sleek re-sizable" layouts

Comment: i appreciate it but I am not looking for any plug-ins or 3rd party tools. This can be done using html and css alone so that is the route I am trying to go:)

Comment: When you say preserves its layout do you mean it scales up and not down?  "All Monitors" can be any display device and that means just about any size.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you forget about setting a fixed size on the parent and set the parent's width to 100% which would give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Thats not what im looking for though. When I try to re-size when the parent node is set to 100% the layout changes, in short, your suggestion does not work.